# Using Properties Store; adding to an array of info, retrieving info

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have an Add-on I'm updating for Sheets. I want to store information each time the user runs one of two functions, so I've created a function to push than info to Document Properties. Ultimately I want to send that data to a sheet at my end once a certain number of values have been collected.
The problem I'm having is that when I run a test function to Log the data contained, it only shows me the most recent data; I'm not sure I'm adding to existing data or replacing it. The data pairs should include the user's email address and the name of the sheets tab created by one of two functions that call this storeStats function.
In short:
*Do I need to declare the name of the Property Store before adding data to it?
*How do I add more data without deleting the old?
*How can I check how much data is stored? I'm thinking along the lines of array.length, but not sure if that works in Properties
*I'm assuming I need to use the parse command to retrieve it and send to the sheet at my end. That may wind up in a separate question later, but any ideas are appreciated.

```
function storeStats(sheetTitle) {
var docProps = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
var userID = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(); 
var thisData = {user:userID, sheet:sheetTitle};
var thisDataStr = JSON.stringify(thisData);
var useData = "USEDATA";  //name of the properties store maybe
docProps.setProperties(useData,thisDataStr);
Logger.log(useData.length);
//send when enough values are present
//use parse to extract and send?
// /*if(/*see how many values are in the data set*/) {
   //parse values from value set array 
   //send the whole batch to the range on the collection sheet
//} */
```

}

No errors are created thus far, but this only returns one email address and one sheet name rather than all values send from previous function calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`docProps.setProperties(useData,thisDataStr);` is not adding data to "USEDATA" if you want to add or append data to it you need to do something like this:

`docprops.setProperty('USEDATA', docprops.getProperty('USEDATA') + thisDataStr);`

Example:

```
function propertiesTest() {
  var ps=PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  ps.setProperty('test','');
  for(var i=0;i<10;i++) {
    ps.setProperty('test',ps.getProperty('test') + '\n' + i)
  }
  Logger.log(ps.getProperty('test'));
}
```

Comment: That works--I think. Logger.log now returns the following. Should all the data be in quotes?  [19-07-12 07:21:41:699 PDT] {USEDATA=null{"user":"emailAdress@gmail.com","sheet":"07/11/2019"}{"user":"bulletinator@gmail.com","sheet":"Script 07/11/2019"}{"user":"bulletinator@gmail.com","sheet":"07/12/2019"}{"user":"bulletinator@gmail.com","sheet":"Script 07/13/2019"}{"user":"bulletinator@gmail.com","sheet":"Script 07/13/2019"}}

Comment: The PropertiesService stores the data as a string.